# Retrieve values from XML File

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, key-value

I have Multiple XML Files that look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema>
<sp_transaction_id name="sp_transaction_id" value="1" />
<sp_year name="sp_year" value="2015" />
<sp_first_name name="sp_first_name" value="James" />
<sp_gender name="sp_gender" value="Male" />
<sp_date_of_birth name="sp_date_of_birth" value="06-06-1999" />
</schema>
```

The XML Format i think is in Key-Value Pairs.
I want to extract these values and store it into a database(SQL Server 2012) table, with the name(eg; sp_year) as Column Name and value(eg; 2015) as the Column value using ASP.NET C#. 
I think i can upload the file and read it like this :

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName;
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
string xml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

But thats pretty much it  ( Sorry Im a beginner ). Please Guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the key value pairs

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var schemaElement = doc.Element("schema");
foreach (var xElement in schemaElement.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xElement.Attribute("name").Value + ":" + xElement.Attribute("value").Value);
    }
```

Elements method returns all elements inside schema element.

However I suggest changing xml file to this format, if possible

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema>
<KeyValuePair name="sp_transaction_id" value="1" />
<KeyValuePair name="sp_year" value="2015" />
<KeyValuePair name="sp_first_name" value="James" />
<KeyValuePair name="sp_gender" value="Male" />
<KeyValuePair name="sp_date_of_birth" value="06-06-1999" />
</schema>
```

Comment: Thanks For your Help, This answer Helped me Solve my Problem....Appreciate It Much

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from an xml file you don't need to upload it.You can give path of xml and read from it.You can use following method to read from xml

```
public static XmlDocument LoadXmlDocument(string xmlPath)
    {
        if ((xmlPath == "") || (xmlPath == null) || (!File.Exists(xmlPath)))
            return null;

        StreamReader strreader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
        string xmlInnerText = strreader.ReadToEnd();
        strreader.Close();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlInnerText);

        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

For reading data from xml you can use

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = LoadXmlDocument(xmlPath);

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc .SelectNodes("//*");

                foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
                {
                  .
                  .
                  .
                }
```

In foreach loop you can get your required values e.g sp_year

Answer (score 1):

The answer below shows how to create an XmlDocument from it.
I would suggest to use it as a User-Defined class if you know whether Xml schema change.
First of all you should create POCO class appropriate to Xml file schema using XmlAnnotations.
Secondly:
Having path of the file:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(definedclass));
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(pathtofile))
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
{
    var xmlObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
}
```

xmlObject is now your user-defined class with values from xml.
Regards,
Rafal

Answer (score 1):

You can load the files into an XDocument & then use Linq-To-XML to extract the required information. The example code below loads all name/value pairs into an array of class :

```
class MyXMLClass
{
  public String FieldName { get; set; }
  public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

The code gets all "schema" descendants (just one as it is the top level element), then selects all elements inside the & creates a new class object for each extracting the name & value.

```
  XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
  MyXMLClass[] xe =
    xd.Descendants("schema")
      .Elements()
      .Select(n => new MyXMLClass {FieldName = n.Attribute("name").Value, Value = n.Attribute("value").Value})
      .ToArray();
```